# When your build failed in automated process

Tags: unix, ssh, ant, build, automation

I have a script that does the 'build' in several servers once I run it. I am now trying to figure out how to know if build failed. For example, the script will run the 3 commands(shown below), how would I know if my pre-build failed?
During the build process I have to run the following commands:

```
./ant pre-build
./ant install1
./ant post-build
```

I can use ssh, puppet etc. in my Redhat machine, and don't have anything more than that. Is there an application or a management tool that will let me monitor my build process in UI?

Comment: Have you checked [Jenkins](https://jenkins-ci.org/)?

Comment: Seconded, use Jenkins. There are plugins that allow you to create a build pipeline with interdependent jobs. Jenkins will then track the progress of each build and tell you which step failed.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the return code of the ant executable as mentioned in the [Running Apache Ant](https://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html):

> the ant start up scripts (in their Windows and Unix version) return the return code of the java program. So a successful build returns 0, failed builds return other values.